# Cancel Asynctask making a TCP/UDP call

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask, udp

These questions refer to the same problem but non has a concrete answer.

- [Cancel an AsyncTask inside itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948341/cancel-an-asynctask-inside-itself)
- [killing asynctask when doInBackground hangs on a TCP Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725542/killing-asynctask-when-doinbackground-hangs-on-a-tcp-socket)

My problem is:

- I have an AsyncTask which is to run every 10 secs and listen for a response from a UDP socket.(Used a timer task to implement the repetitive calls).
- This response might not be available so, **I want to cancel/timeout this Async Task after 3 secs. Not sure How?**

As currently the Asynctasks created after every 10 secs, seem to wait and No other request can be made from the application using some other async task.

Have tried  `.cancel(true);` but `onCancelled()` or `onCancelled(String result)` are not getting called(where I take care of the timer) after this and requests are still being made after every 10 secs

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample code ?

Comment: I think the socket timeout thing is a good solution

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that worked for me is that instead of focusing Async task to timeout, I should be focusing on the socket connection to timeout. I have done that for now by setting socket timeout time using `socket.setSoTimeout(10000)`, which seems to be working.